# How to delete a column that has certain data in using query

Tags: mysql

The object 'DF__tbl_Ncust__Npric__21B6055D' is dependent on column 'column'.
ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN 'column' failed because one or more objects access this column.

Comment: GO into the information schema, find the columns with foreign key relations, break those relations first, then you can delete your column

Comment: sir,there is no other table, I face the problem in just a single table. and there is no primary and foreign key.